# Importing classes from app in django

Tags: python, django

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must
>   either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try doing what it's telling you to?

Comment: Similar to this. You can have a look.[error when using django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081369/error-when-using-django-template) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably importing the models from a Python console
You should use:

```
python manage.py shell
```

instead. This will load the settings module of your project

Comment: Even In The shell,same problem occured.

Comment: Now the problem is soved.

Comment: @tufelkinder I've been able to solve the same issue calling `settings.configure()` before accessing settings as the docs says. In particular, I moved `from django.db import models` after the call to configure. HTH